# Returning from a function enters an infinite loop Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am trying to test the speed of various pointer speeds and ran into a really weird problem. When allocating for raw pointers, it runs fine. (There is a memory leak, but that isn't the problem.) When I run the second test with shared_ptr, It runs the fill fine, prints the log and then when it returns, it enters an infinite loop. It appears the ref count is garbage, but I'm doing everything by value.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

static const int TOTAL = 1000000;

int* newTest(int i)
{
  return new int(i);
}

shared_ptr<int> sharedTest(int i)
{
  return shared_ptr<int>(new int(i));
}

template <typename T>
pair<int, vector<typename T::result_type>> Fill(T fn)
{
  unsigned long start = GetTickCount();
  vector<typename T::result_type> vec;
  vec.reserve(TOTAL);
  for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++)
  {
    vec.push_back(fn(i));
  }
  unsigned long end = GetTickCount();
  return make_pair(end - start, move(vec));
}

template <typename T>
void Test(T fn, string name)
{
  vector<typename T::result_type> newTest;
  int milliseconds = 0;
  tie(milliseconds, newTest) = Fill(fn);
  cout << "Fill " << name << " Took " << milliseconds << " milliseconds." << endl;
}

int main()
{
  function<int*(int)> fn1 = newTest;
  Test(fn1, "Raw Ptr");

  function<shared_ptr<int>(int)> fn2 = sharedTest;
  Test(fn2, "Shared New");

  return 0;
}
```

OK. It appears I have asked a stack overflow question on Stackoverflow....
When I set TOTAL to 10000 it's fine. So, is that just a symptom of something else or do I need to increase my stack size?

*Edit from comment:*

> Tavison: OK. after several minutes it ended. You're right about not being an infinite loop. But, 1043 ms to new and many minutes to delete makes it hard to justify using them. This is not a result I would expect.

Comment: Try doing a clean build.  That code worked fine for me.

Comment: I did that. Tried release and debug as well.

Comment: You may be hitting some strange limit, but your stack size is very manageable for any value of `TOTAL`.

Comment: From your comment below, it sounds like the *strange limit* you hit was physical memory, forcing swap memory to be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no infinite loop, you're just being impatient. It's taking time to free all the `shared_ptr`'s.

To be able to claim there is an infinite loop, you need to actually step into the code and take a look. Check that there is some loop somewhere with a condition that will never change. This is not the case here.

---

Lower your `TOTAL`, for example, and verify it actually ends. Having more of these will not magically introduce an infinite loop at some number, so if it works at a lower number, it works at a higher one.

Or, don't allocate `int`s; allocate some test struct that outputs `"bye"` (along with some counter) when its destructing, and you'll see "post"-test that they're all being deleted. (Of course, performing IO will increase the destruction time, but the point is to verify a condition is moving towards stopping a loop.)

Also, you can cut the allocations in half by using `return make_shared<int>(i);` rather than `new`ing the int yourself and putting it into a `shared_ptr`. Always use `make_shared`.

Lastly, this is only slow if you have a debugger attached, because it'll, well, debug your memory usage. That is, verify that what you're deleting is sensible to delete, isn't corrupting anything, etc.

<sub>And for the love of programming use four spaces to indent, not two.</sub>

Comment: OK. after several minutes it ended. You're right about not being an infinite loop. But, 1043 ms to new and many minutes to delete makes it hard to justify using them. This is not a result I would expect.

Comment: @Tavison: See my edit; this only happens with a debugger attached. Also, justify using *what*?

Comment: Make shared is also in the test set, but I trimmed the question to only what's relevant to the problem. I'm not seeing make_shared that much faster, about 50%. I used ints as an object that would most closely test only the pointer type itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Tavison: 50% is what to expect, as it cuts allocations in half. (And I personally find 50% speed increase quite large but okay.) But back to the question, what are you trying to justify? You have me thinking you're going to avoid `shared_ptr` because of some perceived performance issue. This is not appropriate reasoning, if that's the case.

Comment: No. That's not the case. We're using them fine. The test is to have demonstrable proof they are not a performance problem. Not everyone has entered the enlightenment and need hard proof. Some are willing to consider, but want to know exactly what the trade off is. Even among the various new pointers there are trade offs. I am curious about some performance implications such as locking weak pointers, passing by reference or raw observer pointer and other cases.

Comment: 2 is our in house standard indent.

Comment: @Tavison : If your code ever actually deleted the objects newed in `newTest` then the comparison would be much more realistic. Right now you're measuring `new` vs `new` + `delete` – not exactly fair.

Answer (score 4):

If you run the code in debug or release with debugging, you'll get a debug heap that can be used to track memory errors. Freed memory is filled with debug patterns when this happens, so the code will run slower. Running the code without debugging from Visual Studio ends in less than 200 milliseconds.